# Does anybody know the socket.io client library for c language?

Tags: socket.io

I am writing a application for SCM, and have a server created by socket.io.
so, does anybody know the socket.io client library for c language?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd find [Cellophaneio](http://cellophaneio.sourceforge.net/) helpful?

There are C++ libraries available, but I assume you want just pure C.